# Is there any problems with creating too many rooms in socket.io?

Tags: socket.io

I'm thinking about making a room for every user that connects based on their user id. Will I run into memory problems doing things this way? Or will the rooms disappear when all the connected clients in that room are gone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A room in socket.io is just a Javascript object with a list of sockets in it.  A room only exists as long as there is a socket in it.  As soon as the last socket in a room either disconnects or leaves the room, the room object itself is removed.

In case you didn't realize, socket.io already creates a room for each user based on the `socket.id` value.  So, that already exists.

> Will I run into memory problems doing things this way?

A room is not a large data structure and they are automatically cleaned up when there are no sockets in them so I would not expect you to have memory issues with rooms.

> Or will the rooms disappear when all the connected clients in that
>   room are gone?

Yes, a room will be freed when all the connected clients in that
room are gone.

Rooms are stored in the adapter object (which allows an architecture where distributed rooms across multiple servers via redis can be supported) so the `socket.leave(room)` method ends up telling the adapter to remove the socket from a room.  The adapter code looks like this:

```
Adapter.prototype.del = function(id, room, fn){
  this.sids[id] = this.sids[id] || {};
  delete this.sids[id][room];
  if (this.rooms.hasOwnProperty(room)) {
    this.rooms[room].del(id);
    if (this.rooms[room].length === 0) delete this.rooms[room];
  }

  if (fn) process.nextTick(fn.bind(null, null));
};
```

You can see there that after the socket has been removed from the room, the code checks to see if the current length is `0` and, if so, it deletes the room object.